# Stack Overflow Talent link doesn't have tooltip

Tags: bug, tooltips, footer

Stack Overflow Talent link in the page footer doesn't have tooltip:

> [image: talent]

Any other site's links have it. E.g. Area 51:

> [image: area51]

Comment: Well, maybe there's nothing to say about it... :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard due to no talents ...